# How to run a Playwright test without using the command line

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I want to run a playwright test without typing npx playwright test in the command line. My hope is that I can call a playwright file from another file and have it start running without accessing the command line. Is there any way to add a playwright test to another file so that I can run it multiple times or loop the test without typing in the terminal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you would like to use playwright as a library instead of a test runner. Here is an example of a function that opens a website and takes a screenshot (using Playwright as a library):

```js
const { webkit } = require('playwright');
    
const performScreenshot = async () => {
  const browser = await webkit.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  await page.screenshot({ path: `example.png` });
  await browser.close();
};
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/library

Answer (score 0):

First file

```
// myTest.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('sample test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');
  const title = await page.title();
  expect(title).toBe('Stackoverflow');
});
```

Second file

```
// runTests.js
const { runTests } = require('@playwright/test/lib/cli/cli');

async function runMyTest() {
  await runTests({
    files: ['./myTest.spec.js'], // Array of test files to run
    report: false,
    headed: true,
  });
}


// Run the test multiple times
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(`Running test iteration ${i + 1}`);
    await runMyTest();
  }
  console.log('All test iterations completed');
})();
```

Then you can try to run your test multiple times or loop the test without typing in the terminal

```
node runTests.js
```

Comment: thank you for this solution, can we add a paramaeter to test from the runTests.js ? thank you

Comment: sounds good, doesn't work (anymore?): `Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/cli/cli' is not defined by "exports" `

Answer (score -1):

Playwright tests can be run without using the CLI command. Playwright is a Node.js library, so you can write your test scripts in a Node.js file and then run the file using Node.js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).